# How to make sibling axis categories of a pivot chart independent of each other?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following Pivot Chart. What I want to accomplish is to make each Main column feel like its own section. I tried adding horizontal (or vertical, it appears like Excel uses them interchangeably sometimes) axis gridlines, but it adds them at the level of the date. So it looks like each date is a new section vs. what I am showing in the first photo below.

The second photo is what I do not want. The first photo is what I want

Additionally, is there a way to divide the line chart per the grouping I have shown? The difference between the BS, EO, DF are essentially different products. I am wanting to see the growth per product. Not the deltas between each product.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this workaround if it may help you get started. For the moment I cannot think of any other workaround using pivot chart. However, without editing your table, I do not think it is possible. In my solution, I inserted a new row after each group and wrote a single space as date and then #N/A for values so the line will break.

Example

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion.